# Wordpress Admin Tables in Post View

Tags: posts, admin, wp-list-table

I'm trying to add my custom Wordpress table (similar to the links table) into the "New Post" view of a custom post type. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the only way that I found to do this is wrap the WordPress table in a custom meta box. This is not ideal, because I would like to see the table span the entire container, but it works.